# Injective linear mapping maps every plane to a plane through the origin?

Tags: linear-algebra

Why an injective linear mapping from $R^3 \to R^3$ maps every plane to a plane through the origin?

I can not understand this. It says also that if the mapping is not injective, it maps some line to a point 0. Why this is correct and this is not: plane to a point 0, plane to a line, line to a line and line to a plane.

Comment: If $v_1, v_2$ spans a plane $L$, then $fv_1, f v_2$ are linear independent vectors in the image.

Comment: The statement is not precise. Planes (without restriction) are not mapped to planes through the origin. After all the identity map is injective and linear, and it does not magically transform planes into planes through the origin. Please correct it, or else it won't be clear what you are asking about precisely.

Comment: This is a statement from a book: it says every plane $\Pi$ is mapped to a plane through the origin with that linear mapping.

Comment: @John and with that we can conclude that they span a plane going through the origin?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: But is every plane mapped to a such plane or just the original planes going through the origin? @John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the (linear) map $f$ is not injective, its kernel is not 0, i. e. there is an element $v=(a,b,c)\ne (0,0,0)$ such that $f(v)=0$. As $f$ is linear, for all $\lambda\in\mathbf R$, $$f(\lambda v)=\lambda f(v)=\lambda0=0.$$
Hence the whole line directed by $v$ maps to $0$.

Now there might be two linearly independent vectors that map to $0$. In such a case, it is  the whole plane directed by the vectors that map to $0$. If there are $3$ linearly independent vectors in the kernel, the map is the $0$ map.

Answer (score 1):

If a linear map $T: \Bbb V \to \Bbb W$ is not injective, there is some nonzero vector $v \in \Bbb V$ such that $T v = 0$. Then, $T$ maps the line $\langle v \rangle$ to the origin.

It is possible for a linear map $T$ to map a $k$-plane to an $l$-plane for any $l \leq k$, and so can map a plane to a point, or a plane to a line, or a line to a line (or all three of these at once). But a linear map cannot map a $k$-plane (on)to an $l$-plane for $l > k$, and in particular cannot map a line (on)to a plane.

On the other hand, if $T$ is injective, it maps linearly independent sets to linearly independent sets and hence $k$-planes through the origin to $k$-planes through the origin.